# Ubuntu private and public network via static routing

Tags: networking, ubuntu, routing

I'm trying to configure Ubuntu to have a public and a private networking configuration. I have two NIC's, which both have an active connection. I've tried to use some routing rules, but I fail every time to get it working properly.

My interfaces-file looks as follow:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Private network (behind router)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    subnet 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# Public network
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 141.134.***.*** (I've hidden my real public ip-address here)
    subnet 255.255.255.255
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I want to use the public interface for all default traffic (e.g. ping-command). The private network should only be accessible when using the 192.168.1.x/24 ip-range.

My server is running as a Qemu-KVM host, so I will be putting these interfaces into bridged version later on (first want to get this working on the host), but that shouldn't be much of a problem.

I hope someone can help me with the right static routes for this to work. Both network interfaces should just be separated so that no traffic for public goes through the private and vice versa. The problem I'm facing is that all my server (host) traffic uses the private network which is also connected to the internet (behind router). My public interface does not have a gateway, which is why Ubuntu uses my private interface as default (I suppose?).

Comment: If you want to keep packets coming in on eth0 from getting forwarded out on eth1 and vice versa, you should set up iptables rules , not routing table entry.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Larssend. I first want to be able to ping my public ip-address, which is not possible by default. When I run 'ip route show', I see: 'default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 '. Which indicates that all my traffic will use my private network instead of the public one. I can't seem to get a gateway from my public interface, which is why Ubuntu defaults to the 192.168.1.1 from my private interface (eth0).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to have my public interface as my default. I've done this by adding a gateway for that interface and removing the one from the private interface. I was not getting any gateway before on the public interface (at least, this is what I thought), but that has been fixed by removing the gateway from the private one, then setting public to dhcp.

I can now also access my server with it's public ip-address! However, I wonder if this is safe and if it is still possible to access the private network through the public one and vice-versa. It should not be able to do that. If an application wants to use the private network, it should define that, and not use the public one to access the private (I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I want to make sure my configuration is safe).